# Why selenium webdriver instance variable "timeouts" {implict, pageload, script} not updated when new timeout is set?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

In the following script, Selenium does not update the instance variables with new set timeout.
Can someone please explain reason behind this?

```
import pprint
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.facebook.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
pprint.pp(driver.__dict__['capabilities']['timeouts'])

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
pprint.pp(driver.__dict__['capabilities']['timeouts'])

driver.set_script_timeout(10)
pprint.pp(driver.__dict__['capabilities']['timeouts'])

driver.set_page_load_timeout(200)
pprint.pp(driver.__dict__['capabilities']['timeouts'])

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
{'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000} 
{'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}
{'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000} 
{'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the dictionary returned in the `capabilities` map from the session creation is a snapshot of the initial conditions. It is essentially a record of the values the session was started with. The values of the `capabilities` map is *not* a live-updating object that will change if things in the session change. To get the new timeout values, you need to call the WebDriver command to get the currently set timeouts. In Selenium's Python language bindings, the following should give you something like what you'd expect:

```
# WARNING: Code written from memory without execution
# It may require modification to run without error
import pprint
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.facebook.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
pprint.pp(driver.__dict__['capabilities']['timeouts'])

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.set_script_timeout(10)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(200)

timeouts = driver.timeouts
pprint.pp(timeouts)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @JimEvans for taking time to answer the question. However, `timeouts = driver.timeouts ` results in **AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'timeouts''**

Comment: @KarimShaikh That is going to very much depend on which version of the python language bindings you're using. If you're using [current sources](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L1041), I'm quite sure that property is there. You can update to the 4.0 alpha releases, and it will be there for certain.